# How to return an Error when it contains a reference?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a Rust method that returns a `Result<_, MyError>`. This method is run on a `State` struct and `MyError` has a lifetime specifier `'a` because it needs to keep some `&str`s.

I'm trying to write a trait like this:

```
trait MyTrait {
    type Error;

    fn work(&self) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
}

impl<'a> MyTrait for MyImpl<'a> {
    type Error = MyError<'a>;

    fn work(&self) -> Result<(), MyError<'a>> {
        let state = State::new();

        state.work() // returns Result<(), MyError> but state doesn't live long enough
    }
}
```

How can I get around this error? Should I change `MyError` to keep `String` instead of `&'a str`? Should I keep the `state` inside of `MyImpl`? Is this `trait` well-defined?

I want to create a `State` for every run of `do()`.

Here is an MCVE:

```
enum MyError<'a> {
    Some(&'a str),
}

trait MyTrait {
    type Error;

    fn work(&self) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
}

struct MyImpl<'a> {
    pub some_string: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> MyTrait for MyImpl<'a> {
    type Error = MyError<'a>;

    fn work(&self) -> Result<(), MyError<'a>> {
        let state = State::new();

        state.work() // returns Result<(), MyError> but state doesn't live long enough
    }
}

struct State;

impl State {
    pub fn new() -> State {
        State
    }

    pub fn work(&self) -> Result<(), MyError> {
        Err(MyError::Some("hi"))
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1113cf64d37ba6ed7134e322e5e89471&version=stable))

Comment: You also didn't provide the definition of `MyError` and how exactly `State::work()` creates `MyError`. If it indeed contains string slices which are bound to the lifetime of `state`, it would be impossible to return `MyError` because `state` gets destroyed right there in `MyImpl::work()`.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev That is obviously the issue, but how can I bind them to `MyError` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that according to the signature of `State::work()` the lifetime parameter of `MyError` becomes tied to that of `&self` reference:

```
// without lifetime elision
pub fn work<'a>(&'a self) -> Result<(), MyError<'a>>
```

And afterwards this value is returned in `MyImpl::work()`:

```
fn work(&self) -> Result<(), MyError<'a>> {
    let state = State::new();

    state.work()
}
```

The problem is, lifetime parameter `'a` in `impl<'a> MyTrait for MyImpl<'a>` denotes a lifetime which is *strictly larger* than that of `MyError` returned by `State::work()`. Why it is so? Well, let's look at `MyImpl::work()` again:

```
fn work(&self) -> Result<(), MyError<'a>> {
    let state = State::new();
    state.work()
}
```

Remember that `State::work(&self)` returns a `MyError` with lifetime tied to that of `&self`, that is, in this particular case it will be the lifetime of `state`. The latter, being a local variable, is destroyed immediately after `work()` returns.

However, `'a` in `impl<'a> MyTrait for MyImpl<'a>` denotes the lifetime of a string slice stored in `MyImpl` (that is, in `self`). Naturally, because `MyImpl::work()` can be called at all, it means that the value it is called at is in a valid state and holds a slice which is alive. Therefore, its lifetime is larger than anything which can be created inside `MyImpl::work()`. So it is unsound to return anything which is not derived from this string slice inside `MyImpl`; for example, this is valid:

```
impl<'a> MyTrait for MyImpl<'a> {
    type Error = MyError<'a>;

    fn work(&self) -> Result<(), MyError<'a>> {
        Err(MyError::Some(self.some_string))
    }
}
```

Now the lifetime of `MyError` value is exactly that of `self.some_string`, and the borrow checker becomes happy.

Now, what options are there? First, the simplest approach would be to store an owned `String` inside `MyError`:

```
enum MyError {
    Some(String)
}

impl<'a> MyTrait for MyImpl<'a> {
    type Error = MyError;

    fn work(&self) -> Result<(), MyError> {
        let state = State::new();
        state.work()
    }
}

struct State;

impl State {
    pub fn new() -> State {
        State
    }

    pub fn work(&self) -> Result<(), MyError> {
        Err(MyError::Some("hi".into()))
    }
}
```

This, I believe, is the most idiomatic and the most flexible approach. It is actually very uncommon to have non-self-sufficient error values; I think I've never seen one before. Another alternative would be to use `&'static str`:

```
enum MyError {
    Some(&'static str)
}

struct State;

impl State {
    pub fn new() -> State {
        State
    }

    pub fn work(&self) -> Result<(), MyError> {
        Err(MyError::Some("hi"))
    }
}
```

This approach won't allow you to create error messages dynamically (you can only use string literals for your error messages) but it is more efficient because it does not require allocations for the unhappy path in your program and it may be sufficient for your use cases.